# ¿Hay algo tan fácil en javascript como en Python para tomar un elemento de dos?

Tags: javascript, array

Para una lista: l = [1,2,3,...98,99], con Python podemos hacer `l[0::2]`. ¿Hay algo tan fácil en javascript como en Python para tomar un elemento de dos?

He visto aqui:

```
let x = l.filter((element, index) => {
  return index % 2 === 0;
})
```

Pero Todavía  es un poco complicado.

Comment: En JavaScript el tipo de dato es Array, no lista.

Comment: quieres tomar los indices pares de un array?

Answer (score 2):

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) puede ser lo que buscas:

```js
console.log(['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro'].splice(2, 2))
```

O si no queires alterar el arreglo entonces [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice) ayudaria tambien:

```js
console.log(['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro'].slice(0, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes el método [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice) que te permite extraer una parte del array original indicando la posición de inicio y final.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const firstThree = numbers.slice(0, 3);
```